Adjust GeoTIFF in QGIS Georeferencer
I have 600 GeoTIFFs, old maps, that are roughly rectified by the map corners. I want to improve them with more GCPs so that the internal scale that differs a bit gets more correct.
Is there a way to get the Georeferencer tool to automatically set the corners of the map as GCPs in the Georeferencer tool? It would greatly improve the speed of my work if I already from start has the correct corner GCPs set and I just need to add some more GCPs within that map.

"...rectified by the map corners"  are these the corners of the image file, or the corners of the map area, not including the marginalia?

The map area corners. So the map is where it should be in the corners. But since it's old maps the internal scale in the map is not entirely correct, so I want to add more GCPs to adjust it a bit. And in some cases the corner GCPs is a bit misplaced. But it would be a huge help of the corners of the map area could be visible and loaded in the Georeferencer from start. Then it would be placed at least some what correct and I can just adust or add GCPs instead of starting from scratch

There are lots of research papers about automatic detection of map sheet corners, as well as buildings and other features. For example https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323698694_3D_Reconstruction_of_Urban_History_Based_on_Old_Maps and https://ica-proc.copernicus.org/articles/4/38/2021/ica-proc-4-38-2021.pdf. However, I do not know if anybody has made a QGIS plugin for that purpose.

I think you misunderstood. I have the corners more or less correctly placed. What I want to know is there is a way to get the corner points visible/imported in the Georeferencer tool when I open the image. It would speed up the process of adjusting the map and/or add more GCPs if the map is already nearly on the right spot

Do you mean that you have ground control points saved into the image? If you run gdalinfo my_image.tif, do you get a list of ground control points?

No, I mean the GeoTiff must have some form of coordinates saved since its placed more or less correctly on the map. I was thinking if there is a way to get the corners of the map marked as GCPs in the Georeferencer. If so then I can see these points in the map on both places and it would be easier to identify where the map is in "the real map" and therefore easier/quicker to add new GCPs. Or am I thinking wrong here?

Ok, I understand now. There is enough information in GeoTIFF and for example gdalinfo shows it. It prints the size of the image in pixels, and by that it is possible to get the pixel coordinates for the 4 corners. And gdalinfo prints also the corner coordinates in georeferenced units. All that is missing is a script that writes out a QGIS style .points file with 4 ground control points by this information. Good idea.
